# Trying to edit a message that is displayed by innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies

I am trying to edit the welcome message I have for a site using css. I currently have a message that displays if it is the first time a user vists the site and another if they are a repeat user using cookies. I am trying to edit the message div using css. 
Here is my JavaScript code that picks which message to display using cookies:

```js
window.onload = function welcomeMessage(){ 
  var visitData = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  if (visitData.length == 0)
   document.getElementById('welcome').innerHTML = "<h4>Welcome back to our website!</h4>";
  else
   document.getElementById('welcome').innerHTML = "<h4>Welcome to our website. Please browse the site to learn about our services.</h4>";
  var expiresDate = new Date();
  expiresdate.setFullYear(expiresDate.getFullYear() - 1);
  document.cookie = encodeURIComponent("expires=" + expiresDate.toUTCString());
 }
```

I have the message displayed like this on the html:

```
<div id="welcome"></div>
```

I would like to use css to align the text and possibly more like add a border. For some reason when I try to use a css file to style it won't work on the div.  I don't know if it is because the function uses innerHTML or what. 
I am new to JavaScript so any advice would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly give style attributes to 'welcome' id. No need to give by javascript.

eg.

```
<style>
#welcome {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ff0000 #0000ff;
}
</style>
```

by js you can follow this way:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("welcome").style.color = "blue";
</script>
```